# Display selected dropdown value from database (i.e.mysql)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I've saved the value of the apple from the select drop down to the mysql.
Now in the edit page, i'd like to show the respective value.
But i dont seems to get it right

```html
<?php $food = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['food']); ?>

<select id="food" required name="food" >

    <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Food</option>
    <option value="apple" <?php if($food == apple) 
    echo "selected='selected'"; ?>Apple</option>
    
    <option value="kiwi" <?php if($food == kiwi) 
    echo "selected='selected'"; ?>Kiwi</option>
</select></div>
```

Comment: String should be enclosed by single quotes or double quotes  if($food == 'apple')

Answer (score 0):

```html
<select id="food" required name="food" >

    <option value="" >Select a Food</option>
    <option value="apple" <?php if($food == "apple") 
    echo "selected='selected'"; ?>Apple</option>
    
    <option value="kiwi" <?php if($food == "kiwi") 
    echo "selected='selected'"; ?>Kiwi</option>
</select></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`String` should be enclosed by `single` quotes or `double` quotes   `if($food == 'apple')`

```
<select id="food" required name="food" >

    <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Food</option>
    <option value="apple" <?php if($food == 'apple') 
    echo "selected='selected'"; ?>Apple</option>

    <option value="kiwi" <?php if($food == 'kiwi') 
    echo "selected='selected'"; ?>Kiwi</option>
</select></div>
```